# Why do we need allocate_shared instead of adding to make_shared the ability to pass in custom allocators?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, shared-ptr, allocation

I know that shared_ptr has `allocate_shared` which has the following function signature(as an example, there are more overloads):

```
template< class T, class Alloc, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> allocate_shared( const Alloc& alloc, Args&&... args );
```

... which allows us to have our own allocator implementation be used for the construction of a dynamically created object in a `shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::allocate_shared<int>(std::allocator<int>(), 2);
```

I find this syntax strange and unintuitive compared to the stl containers which has a template allocator type:

```
std::vector<T, Alloc=std::allocator<T>>
```

---

I'm not sure if the combination of default template parameter `class Alloc` is possible along with variadic templates, so if it is indeed the case that the committee drove themselves into a corner and this was their only choice, then I'm willing to accept that as an answer. However, assuming that is not the case - why did the standard committee not opt for a syntax like:

```
shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int, std::allocator<int>>(std::allocator<int>(), 2)
```

or even

```
shared_ptr<int, std::allocator<T>> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(2)
```

(the allocator params' can be defaulted for backwards compatibility) but instead create a whole new function for it?

Comment: `std::make_shared<C, std::allocator<C>>(std::allocator<C>(), 2)` is indistinguishable from a request to make a shared pointer holding `C(std::allocator<C>(), 2)`. It would be a breaking change.

Comment: `shared_ptr<int, std::allocator<T>> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(2)` By what magic is `std::make_shared<int>(2)` supposed to know that its return value will eventually be assigned to `shared_ptr<int, SomeAllocator>`, and use that allocator? Do you envision it returning some kind of a proxy class packing all the constructor arguments, delaying the actual allocation until it's assigned? But then, how would that proxy class allocate memory for holding all those arguments?

Comment: I did think hard about the first option and couldn't come up with a way to implement it. I did envision some kind of lazy operation on the second option. I didn't think that the lifetime of whatever was generated from `make_shared` would last long in any C++ program until it was implicit casted to a shared_ptr, so dynamic allocation through new/delete for the duration of its lifetime would be fine. But then it might break existing codebases with `auto ptr = std::make_shared` as it would not be type deduced to a shared_ptr.